# Mixing Firestore auto-generated IDs and Firebase Auth IDs

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an app using Firebase Auth and Firestore where we store user information in the `/users` collection. Some users login and have a Firebase Auth record. Other users don't login, their `/users` documents are just used as reference data.

For Firestore documents in the `/users` Collection that link to Admin records, I am setting the Document ID to the Firebase Auth UUID (28 character ID generated by Firebase Auth). This lets me easily fetch the user information after the user logs in.

For the others, I am creating the user records with the auto-generated 20 character ID Firestore creates via `.doc()` or `.add(newData)`.

Is there any documented risk to this or has Firebase stated anything that makes this unwise? I have found nothing in their Guide/Reference documentation that says one way or the other. Their documentation states you can set the ID or let it be generated for you, but it never says you can mix the two methods in the same collection. Has Firebase stated any guarantees for the length of their IDs (currently Auth uses 28 characters and Firestore uses 20 which guarantees they'd never overlap). Will Firestore auto-create a new ID if the auto-generated ID already exists?

The biggest risk I see is if the implementation changed in the future and both had the same length IDs but I have been unable to find any guarantees one way or the other.

Comment: This doesn't answer your specific questions, but I think in your case you would be much better off using Anonymous Auth for the users who don't login. It will then give you an ID that looks and acts much more like a normal Firebase Auth UUID, and makes it a lot easier for you to "convert" an anonymous user to a signed-in one if they want to sign in later.

Comment: @ToddKerpelman The problem is they never "use" the app so we have no way to generate an anonymous auth for them. My current plan is to create a "/persons" collection with an "authID" field that links to the Auth UID. Then if they decide they need the permission to login later, an auth record can be created and linked that way. It makes fetching the Person (User) record more hassle since it will now require a Query for a single record but it will be more flexible.